# Convert date string to date object using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

there is a situation which I need to convert a date string which consist a timezone abbrevation to a Moment object and parse it. How can I do this? sample date is like below:

```
var dateString = "2015-01-14 06:57:47 ECT";
```

be aware that I need the timezone of this date, because Im going to do another conversion to another zone, so if we just consider the date we miss the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think moment can handle a timezone name, you should replace `ECT` with the offset value, like `+0200`